# How am I supposed to Unit Test a Scala Case Class with Jacoco?

Tags: scala, jacoco, scalatest

I have the following Case Class...

```
case class Test(name:String)
```

and I add the following test...

```
class TestSpec extends AnyFunSpec with should.Matchers{
  describe("Tests"){
    it("Test 1"){
      val item = Test("name")
      item.name should be("name")
    }
  }
}
```

but when I run `mvn test` my Test coverage tool (Jacoco) shows 0%...

[image]

I also tried...

```
it("Test 2"){
  val item = Test("name")
  inside(item){
    case Test(name) =>{
      name should be("name")
    }
  }
}
```

But it is still showing 0%

How am I supposed to Unit Test these items to get the appropriate coverage?

Comment: I would recommend you to use a **Scala** tool instead of a **Java** one, check [**scoverage**](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin) - Also, if this a new project, it would be better to use a **Scala** native build tool like **sbt** or **mill** instead of **maven**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez This won't work thanks to internal libs but thanks for the ideas